# Dash - interaction between 2 apps

Tags: python

I want to set interaction between 2 apps in Dash.
I'm trying to pass the Input value from app to output in app2.
My code is working but I have to manually refresh page with app2.
It work as well, when I change the Input in app2, because input from app2 is an argument in callback function.
But I want to see the input(in app2) changes online

**app code:**

```py
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback

inp =''

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H6("Change the value in the text box to see callbacks in action!"),
    html.Div([
        "Input: ",
        dcc.Input(id='my-input', value='initial value', type='text')
    ]),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(id='my-output'),

])

@callback(
    Output(component_id='my-output', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='my-input', component_property='value')
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    global inp
    inp = input_value
    return f'Output: {input_value}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port = 8050)
```

**and app2 code:**

```py
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback

app2 = Dash(__name__)

app2.layout = html.Div([
    html.H6("Change the value in the text box to see callbacks in action!"),
    html.Div([
        "Input: ",
        dcc.Input(id='my-input', value='initial value', type='text')
    ]),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(id='my-output'),

])

@callback(
    Output(component_id='my-output', component_property='children'),
    Input(app.layout.children[1].children[1].id, 'value'),
    #Input(inp)
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return f'Output: {input_value} + {inp}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app2.run(debug=True, port = 8051)
```

Is it possible to manually refresh app2? I Couldn't find any method like this. Is it possible to use Input value from app in app2 callback function?